# Delete an S3 "folder" using Perl

Tags: amazon-web-services, perl, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use `Net::Amazon::S3` to manipulate an S3 storage bucket for backup rotation. One thing I need to do is delete folders that contain old backups. But, while I can delete files, I cannot get the code to delete even an empty folder.

For example:

```
our $s3 = Net::Amazon::S3->new({
    aws_access_key_id  => 'key_id',
    aws_secret_access_key => 'access_key',
    retry => 1
});

our $bucket_name = 'bucketName';
our $s3Bucket = $s3->bucket($bucket_name);

# Assume bucket 'bucketName' has the following key. This works fine:
$s3Bucket->delete_key('weeklyTest/test.pdf') or say STDERR 'File delete failed:'  . $s3Bucket->errstr;

# Assume bucket 'bucketName' has the following empty key. 
# This fails to happen, but without reporting any error.
$s3Bucket->delete_key('weeklyTest/') or say STDERR 'Folder delete failed:'  . $s3Bucket->errstr;
```

Is there something I'm missing that needs to be done to get a "folder" key to delete?

Comment: S3 does not have folders.  It has shared prefixes.  Generally, deleting all of the objects sharing a prefix is enough.

Comment: That's what I was thinking and I think that code above should empty out the "prefix." I'm just using the folder terminology since that's what the S3 console uses. But, the above /should/ be thinking along the lines you said and it doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: The code removes one object from under a prefix.  To empty it out, you'll need to list the objects and remove each one in turn (or to a single deleteObjects call)

Comment: All the objects have already been deleted or, alternately, I've tried it with a completely empty prefix. It still won't work.

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: The code above that sends a command to delete the empty prefix just doesn't do anything. It works for files, but not "prefix" keys that are functioning as "folders."

Comment: How do you know that?  What have you done to debug that?  Your code doesn't show any attempt to list items, or what the output is.  We're guessing.  If you list objects under a prefix and delete them, baring any permissions oddities, they'll be deleted.

Comment: I'm using the AWS S3 web console to test the result. I've also listed it out using code here and it shows the console is right in indicating it doesn't delete the file. There is no error output generated -- it tests for that.

Comment: Does the bucket have versioning enabled?  Have you verified that there are no old versions of objects in the seemingly "empty" folder?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot it does not have versioning on. So, what I've been doing is creating a folder in the AWS S3 console (using the "create folder" button in there), then immediately attempting to delete it programmatically, which doesn't return an error, but also doesn't delete the "folder."

Comment: If the code you are running matches the code you have posted, this confusing, because deleting the object `foo/` is the correct way to remove the empty, console-created folder `foo`.  The best troubleshooting strategy I can suggest is using the CLI e.g. `aws s3api list-objects` and `delete-object` to try to replicate the behavior and get a better understanding of what might be happening.  You could also consult the bucket logs to ensure this library is attempting what you are asking.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot `delete-object` failed to delete the object, too. And just like with the Perl API, it didn't return an error, it just left the file.

Comment: @TimothyR.Butler use `aws s3api list-objects`.  Confirm whether there is indeed an object named exactly `weeklyTest/`, and whether there are any objects with keys beginning with `weeklyTest/` (which will force that folder to continue to be visible) including unexpected/nonsensical object keys such as `weeklyTest//`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All libraries for AWS services closely track with aws-cli. If you can get things to work with aws-cli, then the process for doing the same programmatically will be similar. I usually do my prototyping with aws-cli to get the syntax/options right, then repeat in code.

delete_key is used for objects is a bucket, but if you want to delete the bucket itself, you need to use delete_bucket.

https://metacpan.org/pod/Amazon::S3#delete_bucket

Comment: Thanks for your help! And welcome to Stack Overflow, too! I'm trying to just delete a prefix or folder, not a bucket, but I'll play around with the cli version more and see if that yields any answers. Thank you!